# Tensor flow installation from source issue in Build your target with GPU support

Tags: tensorflow

This first time for me to install Tensorflow. I followed the instructions on  [official website](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/get_started/os_setup.html#installing-from-sources) here. I installed from source because I found some people advice to do that instead of pip installation. I used version r0.9 of tensorflow and I installed it on Ubuntu-mate 15.10. I followed all instructions. Installed python, cuda version 7.5, cudnn release 5. Nvidia GPU 5200 with compute capability of 2.1. Every thing went well until I reached bazel [build step here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/get_started/os_setup.html#installing-from-sources),

```
Latitude-E6430:~/tensorflow$ bazel build -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/cc:tutorials_example_trainer
```

"Latetude-E6430" is the user of the machine. 
I got the following errors immediately:

```
ERROR: /home/meqdad/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:91:1: //tensorflow/core:protos_all_py: no such attribute 'imports' in 'py_library' rule.
ERROR: /home/meqdad/tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/BUILD:28:1: Target '//tensorflow/core:sparse_ops_op_lib' contains an error and its package is in error and referenced by '//tensorflow/cc:ops/sparse_ops_gen_cc'.
ERROR: Loading failed; build aborted.
```

I tried to find a solution to this problem, I was using bazel 0.1 then I upgraded to bazel 0.3. However, on the net, there is several issues like this one but non of them was related to this one. I re-installed py_library but it did nothing to solve the problem.

Please can you advice me how to move on with this step of installation.